# how to do a search and replace for a string in mssql 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssms-2012

I am having to find and replace a substring over all columns in all tables in a given database.

I tried this code from sqlserver 2012 ssms but resulting in errors from http://www.dbtalks.com/uploadfile/anjudidi/find-and-replace-string-values-in-all-tables-and-column-in-s/ [Find and Replace string Values in All Tables and column in SQL Serve](http://www.dbtalks.com/uploadfile/anjudidi/find-and-replace-string-values-in-all-tables-and-column-in-s/)

I think its for older version, it having problems with some of the tables names that start with a number: example dbo.123myTable

Appreciate all the help in advance

Error Print:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near '.153'.
>   UPDATE dbo.153Test2dev SET [ALCDescription] = REPLACE(convert(nvarchar(max),[ALCDescription]),'TestsMT','Glan') WHERE [ALCDescription] LIKE '%SherlinMT%'
>   Updated: 1
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near '.153'.
>   UPDATE dbo.153TypeTest2 SET [FormTypeDescription] = REPLACE(convert(nvarchar(max),[FormTypeDescription]),'TestsMT','Glan') WHERE [FormTypeDescription] LIKE '%SherlinMT%'
>   Updated: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as a guess, to add delimiters to your table names, modify the script you linked to by editing this line:

```
    SET @sqlCommand = 'UPDATE ' + @schema + '.' + @table + ' SET [' + @columnName + '] = REPLACE(convert(nvarchar(max),[' + @columnName + ']),''' + @stringToFind + ''',''' + @stringToReplace + ''')'
```

and change it to

```
  SET @sqlCommand = 'UPDATE [' + @schema + '].[' + @table + '] SET [' + @columnName + '] = REPLACE(convert(nvarchar(max),[' + @columnName + ']),''' + @stringToFind + ''',''' + @stringToReplace + ''')'
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure table names may begin with a digit? If so, include them in '[' ']', like

```
UPDATE [dbo].[153TypeTest2].....
```

Answer (score 0):

based in  the code you linked to, try this:

```
SET @sqlCommand = 'UPDATE [' + @schema + '].[' + @table + '] SET [' + .....
--add square braces:      ^               ^ ^              ^
```

Answer (score 0):

You should bracket your table name in the same way as the column name  in the update query (see @table now has brackets):

```
SET @sqlCommand = 'UPDATE ' + @schema + '.[' + @table + '] SET [' + @columnName + '] = 
REPLACE(convert(nvarchar(max),[' + @columnName + '])
```